# C# WinForms - How do I fire EditingControlShowing event with code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using DataGridView control for editing some data. During form load, how do I fire `EditingControlShowing` event with code?

Edit: Need to show all cell in Current Row in Edit mode, CurrentCell will show only one cell...

Comment: That's going to be difficult in the Load event, nothing is showing yet.  Use the Shown event instead and call the BeginEdit() method.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `CurrentCell` property to the cell you want to edit and then call `BeginEdit`. This  will result in `EditingControlShowing` being triggered on that cell.

Comment: Can set multiple cell rather than CurrentCell...?

Comment: Not really, because only one cell will have the focus at a time. You may want to experiment with calling `BeginEdit` again when the focus changes?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to fire EditingcontrolShowing on Form Load.

It is used to show some nested control in datagrid view when editing